# changing DNA of an organism

Tags: dna

is it possible at least theoretically to change the DNA of an organism ?

so we take for example an organism with multiple cells then we change its DNA without killing this organism

to correct genetic defects or to improve it

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_therapy).

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but you have to engineer the totipotent stem cell that forms all the other cells in the organism's body. There is no way to alter the DNA of *every single* cell in a human or mouse, for example, after they have begun developing.

Answer (score 1):

Erm. Sort of. Kind of depends on your definition. It hasn't been done for multicellular organisms though.

Craig Venter et al did this exact experiment a few years ago with a completely synthetic Mycoplasma genome.

http://www.jcvi.org/cms/press/press-releases/full-text/article/first-minimal-synthetic-bacterial-cell-designed-and-constructed-by-scientists-at-venter-institute-an/

If you just want to change small segments of DNA that's where cloning and gene therapy come in, and we do that A LOT.